# A value is not being passed onto a class instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a very simple program written in CoffeeScript where if a user clicks on a button a value should be displayed in the console. Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <button id='butn'>click here</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js is the compiled CoffeeScript. My CoffeeScript is below:

**init.coffee**

```
init = =>

  game = new Game()


# Start it all off
$(document).ready(init)
```

---

**game.coffee**

```
class Game

  constructor: () ->

    @UI = new UI()
```

---

**ui.coffee**

```
class UI

  constructor: () ->

    @toolbar = new Toolbar('foo')
```

---

**toolbar.coffee**

```
class Toolbar
  constructor: (@value) ->

    @clickhandler()


  clickhandler: () =>
    $('body').on 'click', '#butn', ->
        console.log 'Value = ', @value
```

---

**The Compiled JS is:**

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function() {
  var Game, Toolbar, UI, init,
    _this = this,
    __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

  init = function() {
    var game;
    return game = new Game();
  };

  $(document).ready(init);

  Game = (function() {

    function Game() {
      this.UI = new UI();
    }

    return Game;

  })();

  UI = (function() {

    function UI() {
      this.toolbar = new Toolbar('foo');
    }

    return UI;

  })();

  Toolbar = (function() {

    function Toolbar(value) {
      this.value = value;
      this.clickhandler = __bind(this.clickhandler, this);

      this.clickhandler();
    }

    Toolbar.prototype.clickhandler = function() {
      return $('body').on('click', '#butn', function() {
        return console.log('Value = ', this.value);
      });
    };

    return Toolbar;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

---

## The Problem

The value 'foo' is not being displayed on the console. The console logs "Value = " but no 'foo'. Please could someone help me understand why and how I can fix this problem without changing too much of my program.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the value of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside the event handler, where it points to the DOM element instead of the Toolbar instance. Use [function binding](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

```
class Toolbar
  constructor: (@value) ->
    @clickhandler()

  clickhandler: () ->
    $('body').on 'click', '#butn', =>
      console.log 'Value = ', @value
```